# Django apps structure

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django but it's difficult to me to see how should I divide a project into apps?

I've worked on some Java EE systems, almost for procedures for government and all that stuff but I just can't see how to create a Django project for this purposes?

For example, if you should have to do a web app for making easier three process: Procedure to get the passport, procedure to get the driver license and procedure to get the social number.

The 3 procedures have steps in common: Personal information, Contact Information, Health Information. Would you do a project for each procedure, an app for each procedure, an app for each step?

I'm sorry if I'm posting this in the wrong Stack Exchange site.

Thank you.

Comment: Your apps should follow the unix philosophy of doing one single thing extremely well, and they should be modularly encapsulated to do that thing anywhere. I need more info to understand how to exactly split your apps up, but each component of the process / features in your project should be its own app.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "procedures" i guess you're talking about pages (or views in Django). So I would implement a single "app" to do that.

Remember a project is composed of apps. When you create a project a main app (with the same name of the project) is created. This is a good place to code the procedures you said.

Think of apps as indepent sections of your project (site); maybe some forum, a blog, a custom administration panel, a game and stuff like that. Every one of them could be an independent app.

A project is mostly intended as a single website, so there's no need to create another project on the example you mentioned.